# Calculating Poker Outs % for the Turn and River

Tags: probability

I've recently gotten into Hold'em Poker and want to know how to calculate the percentages. This is probably very easy maths, but I haven't looked at maths in a while now so I've forgotten how to do a bit of probabilities.

What I want to know is how can I calculate the percentage that the card I want would come out on the Turn OR the River.

Say I have 5 outs (i.e. cards that I want to come out) and there are only 3 cards on the table (the flop). I go all-in. What are the chances (in %) that I'd hit my card? How do I calculate that?

Here's a simple illustration.

XXX _ _

There are 5 cards in the remaining 47 cards left in the deck that I want to come out (47 because I'm holding 2 and there's already 3 on the table).

This might be a very simple problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [poker.stackexchange](http://poker.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This question already exists and is well-answered on Poker SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a rough estimate is: number of REAL outs * 2 per street

this is close enough for almost any decision making

with real outs i mean= you got a str8 and a flushdraw, but no str8 flushdraw, so you shouldnt count your str8draws fully, because some str8s will give you simply a better hand, a flush

If you want a very close calculation, use pokerstove

Comment: How would you go about calculating it precisely? I know the 4-2 rule, but am just curious about how the actual calculation would go. It might be very difficult, but I'm just curious.

Comment: lets say, you got a double str8 draw and you think only your str8 draws will help you (you suspect a 2pair+). So you got 8 outs. Now to hit your draw on the very next street, you have 2*8%=16%, which is close enough to the actual number. If you wanna know the chance for 2 streets, you simply make it 4*8%=32% which is reaally close to the right result. Also, to then calculate, wether you can call a bet on one street, you can simply say: you can only call a potbet mathematicly correct, if you got a monsterdraw (or already a made hand..), or you suspect no action on further streets.

Comment: if you want to calculate wether its ok to call with a 5 outer: the standard solution would be simply no, unless your opponent bets very small (or you play LIMIT).

Comment: I get what you're saying, but what I'm asking is for the actual number. Rather than 2*8=16%, I want to know the actual method to get the precise percentage. I'm not concerned with 'close to the right result'.

Comment: ah ok, then its like you posted in your OP, there are 2 streets to come, you got 5 outs, so 1-42/47*41/46= your chance to hit on 2 streets. Or make it only 1-42/47 for one street. To generalize: 1-(n-outs)/n for one street, where n=number of  unknown cards in the deck

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for.